How do I deploy a Python executable file to an App Service?

I have a Python Flask application, and I built it using PyInstaller, which generated an .exe file and an internal package folder.

I have an Azure App Service (Windows). I deployed the .exe file and internal packages to the /site/wwwroot directory in the App Service and was able to run it on port 8000. However, I'm unable to access the application via the default domain of the App Service.


Could someone please assist or guide me on how to deploy this built .exe file and make the application accessible via the default domain of the App Service?

Use this Environment Variable WEBSITES_PORT = 8000 or if possible change port to 8080. Azure App Service listen to port 8080 by default.

Typical Flask deployment is like this, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ So, you might customize some steps to match your executable.

My guess would be that the App Service does not expose the port or CORS is blocking some stuff. However App Service also supports CI/CD so you might want to look into this. Also never used a windows machine to deploy code it. Here is a reference on how to do this (but it's using linux afaik)
Azure Documentation
